# Join with aggregate function on empty resultset

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement to get sum, avg, count values as 0 following institution_name when lr.proccessed_on date is not matched with the input date. how can I achieve that in the following query

```
  SELECT bd.id                         as institutionId,
   bd.institution_name           as institution,
   count(lr.id)                  as numberOfTransaction,
   sum(lr.amount)           as totalTransactionAmount,
   avg(lr.amount)           as averageTransactionAmount,
   sum(lr.processing_fee)        as totalProcessingFee
from daily_transaction lr
     join
 (
     select s.id
     from status s
     where s.name not in (:statusName)) s on
     lr.customer_status = s.id
     join account sa on
lr.account = sa.id
     join branch b on
sa.branch = b.id
     right join institution_details bd on
b.institution = bd.id
     join status s2 on
bd.status = s2.id
where (:institutionIdParam is null
or bd.id = :institutionIdParam)


 and (:instutionStatus is null
    or s2.description = :instutionStatus)
  and (:fromDate is null
           and :toDate is null
or cast(lr.processed_on as date) <= :toDate
       and cast(lr.processed_on as date) >= :fromDate)
group by bd.id , bd.institution_name
order by bd.institution_name asc;
```

Comment: Can you put in your post input and output samples of data in order to better understand the question?

Comment: if I put the input that is not is lr.processed on then the output returns as empty but I want to get the result as 0 transactions for all the details in the output

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of using **RIGHT JOIN** to **institution_details** seems to be that you want all institutions listed irrespective of their daily transactions. For those institutions where there are no daily transactions processed_on is treated as having NULL value (that is how the right join would behave), and a **WHERE** condition like yours would return **false**, and the institution_details are then filtered out.

You can overcome this by moving your parameter checking clause to the join condition, like so:

```
     right join 
     institution_details bd on
     b.institution = bd.id
     and 
     ((:fromDate is null and :toDate is null) 
       or 
       (cast(lr.processed_on as date) <= :toDate and cast(lr.processed_on as date) >= :fromDate))
```

and removing it from the **WHERE** clause.

Note the brackets I added to your expression; in the presence of both OR and AND operators we need to consider the operator precedence and order of evaluation, it would be incorrect (in my view) not to have these brackets. Even with these, you need to prevent a situation where only one (but not both) :fromDate and :toDate parameters is supplied.

Comment: Did this answer help?